# Nginx client request body is buffered to a temporary file

Tags: nginx

The application is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.3 platform. I have problems uploading images with nginx. use `client_max_body_size` argument to regulate it. When it's equal to 2000 M I see in the logs `client intended to send too large body` When it's 0 I get error 500 When it's 100 M I get `[warn] client request body is buffered to a temporary file`.

I tried to add other lines such as

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_request_buffering off;
client_body_buffer_size 1M;
```

but didn't succeed.

The API works from Postman but fails from Android app. I tried to gradually increase the number but that didn't work.

Comment: There are some [existing answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+client+request+body+is+buffered+to+a+temporary+file%22) that describe this.

Comment: existing answers did not solve my problem.

Comment: I want to upload image with an API but it doesn't succeed from the Android app. But the API works from Postman.

Comment: Are you willing to describe the problem with more detail, potentially error logs or something? You mentioned a `warn` message, which is expected.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, create an endpoint that you can test with while you calibrate the settings.

```
# nginx.conf

server { 
  listen 888;

  location /upload { 
    add_header x-request-$content_length $content_length always;
    add_header x-request-$content_type $content_type always;

    error_page 413 /upload/error;

    location /upload/pass {
      client_max_body_size 1185;
      return 200 $request_uri\n;
    }

    location /upload/fail {
      client_max_body_size 1184;
      return 200 $request_uri\n;
    }

    location /upload/error {
      return 200 "ERROR $status\n";
    }
  }
}
```

```bash
# CREATE TEST FILE

$ fallocate -l 1000 1k.dat
```

```bash
# UPLOAD TEST 1

$ curl -i -F "=@1k.dat" http://localhost:888/upload/pass
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-request-$content_length: 1185
x-request-$content_type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------f4920760a21b19b5

/upload/ok
```

```bash
# UPLOAD TEST 2

$ curl -i -F "=@1k.dat" http://localhost:888/upload/fail
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
x-request-$content_length: 1185
x-request-$content_type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------d3784bc7b1ada368

ERROR 413
```

```bash
# SERVER LOGS

$ tail /var/log/nginx/access.log
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2023:00:11:01 +0000] "POST /upload/pass HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "curl/7.81.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2023:00:11:06 +0000] "POST /upload/fail HTTP/1.1" 413 10 "-" "curl/7.81.0" "-"

$ tail /var/log/nginx/error.log
2023/03/08 00:08:47 [error] 10972#10972: *324 client intended to send too large body: 1185 bytes, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /upload/fail HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:888"
```

Comment: The test file will include the API and send the request right?

Comment: It's a `curl` client that sends the HTTP request. I'm not sure which API you're referencing.

Comment: I don't quit understand how to make this work.